# Xcode Server 4 not seeing any new attached devices

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, server

Xcode Server running on a Mac mini can no longer see any iDevices attached to it.  Initially was able to see an iPhone 4, but no other devices since. Anyone have any suggestions?

Additional info:

- Test Bot is configured to run all Simulators and devices
- Test Bot runs in Xcode 6 and completes tests against Simulators but not any devices
- iPhone Configuration Utility shows attached iDevices as expected
- Xcode 6 on the server (mac mini) can see the attached iDevices
- iDevices have the correct provisioning profiles
- (possibly related) Server's app icon in the dock has a no go/ stop icon overlaid on it:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else encountering this issue: my solution was to just delete the XCode server application and reinstall.